# using try vs TryCatch in R

Tags: r, try-catch, try-catch-finally

My R code is as follows

```
errors = 0

for(i in c(1:100)){

 tryCatch(expr = {
    API Call
  }, error = {errors=errors+1}, finally = {})

  further code
}
```

The code is meant to continue execution even if the API call fails and count the number of times error occurred.
But I see that if for an iteration there is an error in API call, the code is not executed for further iterations.
If I use try(), then I wont be able to count the number of errors.

Answer (score 3):

The `error=` argument of [`tryCatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html) should be a function. If you pre-instantiate `errors <- 0` before the `for` loop, there are a couple of options:

My preferred is to catch and check to see if it inherits `"error"`:

```r
errors <- 0L
for (...) {
  res <- tryCatch({
    ...API call...
  },
    error = function(e) e)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    errors <- errors + 1L
  } else {
    something else here
  }
}
```

Equivalently with `try`:

```r
errors <- 0L
for (...) {
  res <- try({
    ...API call...
  }, silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    errors <- errors + 1L
  } else {
    something else here
  }
}
```

Though the reasons I prefer that may be mostly subjective. Another way would be more internal:

```r
errors <- 0L
for (...) {
  res <- tryCatch({
    ...API call...
  },
    error = function(e) { errors <<- errors + 1L; })
  something else here
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that after running the tryCatch block, the code does not execute further.  The code just stops with an error.

Comment: When your code unmodified, that makes sense: you are not setting `error=` correctly. Compare `tryCatch(stop("hello"), error=function(e)e);message("hello again")` (correct behavior) with `tryCatch(stop("hello"), error={1+1});message("hello again")`

Comment: BTW, I would guess that you might need to shift to something like my first code block, checking `inherits(res, "error")`, because it seems likely that your "further code" relies on something being returned from that api call.

Comment: However, you've only said that your code stops with an error. Are you certain that the error is due to the API call, or is it from the follow-on code? Is it a presumption in the follow-on code that fails because the api call didn't succeed? Is it unrelated, just happens to be outside of the `tryCatch` expression (but still within the `for` loop)? There's a lot of ambiguity here, not much to work on ...

Comment: I don't understand the first code block. Why are you not using `try` there? If you want to store the errors, you shouldn't overwrite `res` in each iteration.

Comment: @Roland, besides the extra characters and needing to check against `"try-error"` instead of `"error"`, is there an advantage to using `try` over `tryCatch`? I don't try to store the errors themselves, and it was not suggested (afaict) in the OP.

Comment: Clarity of code and a tiny bit of performance ...

Answer (score 0):

```
# set up scenario
api_call <- function(in_1){
  if(in_1 %in% c(5,7)){
    stop("bad num")
  }
  in_1+.5
}

for(i in 1:10){
  print(api_call(i))
}

# wrap it up
library(purrr)
safe_api_call <- safely(api_call)
for(i in 1:10){
  print(safe_api_call(i)$result)
}

# add counting of errors

error_count <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
  r <- safe_api_call(i)
  print(r$result)
  error_count <- error_count + inherits(r$error,"error")
}
error_count
```